# Database Architecture for User Ratings

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

This is probably a really simple question, but for some reason I can't think of an answer I feel 100% confident with.

I'm putting together a little website about the Oscars for myself and a few friends. I have a table for the **Films**, a table for the **Nominees**, a table for the **Awards** (e.g. Best Film), a table for the **Ceremony** itself (e.g. year it was held, etc.) and a table that links them all: **Nominations**.

The **Nominations** table looks (predictably) like this:

> ```
> NominationID * 
> FilmID 
> AwardID 
> NomineeID 
> CeremonyID
> ```

I'm now going to put together a **Users** table, but I can't think of a good place to store data on these things:

- A user's rating of a given film and/or...
- Whether the user has seen a given film
- A user's prediction of a winning nomination

For the first two, I was thinking of a **UsersFilms** table, which would look something like this:

> ```
> UsersFilmsID *
> FilmID
> UserID
> UserRating
> UserSeenIt (boolean)
> ```

For the third, a **Predictions** table:

> ```
> PredictionsID * 
> NominationID 
> UserID
> ```

Cany anyone give advice on whether this is a good way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a solid schema to me. Good job.

Comment: Thanks! :) Hopefully you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you plan to manage the fact that a nomination can be either a person or a film ?

Did you plan on saving the winners ?

I think you should post the columns you were planning to have for each Table. There's a lot of potential problems I'm thinking about, but maybe you got them all resolved already ;)

For the UsersFilm, since I doubt an user can rate a film prior to seeing it, I don't think the boolean is mandatory, for in my view it will always be true.

And to conclude, I don't think a database modelisation problem can be simple, there's always many different ways to do think and nobodby can ever say "This solution would work in each case".

Comment: That's a good point, but even for something like "Best film" the award is given to people (the producers), not the film itself. Yes, I was planning on saving the winners, so that's another problem to solve :-/ That's true, also, about the Viewing/Rating -- however some people might like to mark it as seen without rating a film.